# Unclear balance

Tags: balances

I have noticed that the balance of my HOGE is much smaller than it should be, according to my calculation (buying minus selling). Is 0.00000217 HOGE. According to the calculation should still be 21090.55 Hodge. How to explain this? Does anyone know?

[image]